# Find all the numbers that satisfy the congruences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is to find all the numbers in the interval [1,700000] that satisfy at the same time the congruences:

$ x\cong 1 (mod 5)$

$x^2 \cong 2 (mod 7)$

I know for example, that $x=11$ is one of this numbers, but I really don't know how to find the other solutions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are asking for a systematic solution, you can note that $x^2=2\mod 7$ is equivalent to $x=3\mod 7$ or $x=4\mod 7$, so you can use Chinese theorem to solve two systems: $x=1\mod 5,\ x=3\mod 7$ and $x=1\mod 5,\  x=4\mod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern will recur every $5\cdot 7=35$, so you can just try them all.  The first says only $1,6,11,16,21,26,31$ are candidates.  I find one other.  Then you can add any multiple of $35$ to these.